# As a US citizen living abroad, how do I obtain a US bank account?

Tags: us-citizens, banking

As a US citizen living overseas, how do I open a US Bank Account?

Comment: Depends on the country really. Each has its own rules and may even have certain regional variations within.

Comment: Does it have to be a US-based account? Or would a USD-denominated account with a local bank work?